# Raspberry Pi 4 not working

Tags: boot-issues, pi-4

I have 2 Raspberry Pi 4 model B's, 4gb of ram (meant to be identical).

I put the SD card in one and the power light is red and the other light is solid green (this is the one that is not working)

The other I put the same SD card into and it boots, screen lights up, keyboard works everything is fine.

The only factor to change is the Pi its self, can I fix this? What is the issue? How do I fix it?

This Pi has worked before, sometimes it boots, sometimes it does not. Have not managed to boot it in a few weeks however it powers up fine.

Comment: Follow the steps in [Pi4 Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151&sid=ec118b286843110a1175ec84a250a7dc#p1485558) and post your findings.

Answer (score 1):

When the Pi sometimes boots and sometimes not, there can be numerous reasons for that:

- A broken or unstable power supply. Swap the PSUs of both Pis and light them up to find out. You should also attach a USB multimeter to check the PSU's output voltage.
- A broken PSU cable
- Damaged pins in the SD card bay. You'll need a magnifier to check.
- Problems with the Pi itself: Firmware fault, some electronic element broken, memory corrupt,… Attach your Pi to an HDMI monitor and look for error messages appearing on the screen.

Comment: The screen is black as the night, I get nothing at all. and the PSU cable is the same as the one that works (as in I only own 1 cable, I just change the Pi with all the same stuff, only the board changes in the set up)

Comment: This may mean that your Pi is broken. As you said, the green LED is on all the time. This could be a sign for a serious issue. :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the power supply. This is the most common problem I've come
   across.
2. Run `memtester` to check if you have a memory problem.

If that doesn't help maybe you should upgrade your

```
sudo rpi-update
```

to update your firmware. This is shouldn't be needed under normal circumstances.

Comment: I am using the same power supply for both Pis (Im only changing the board, same SD card, same power supply, same monitor, same hdmi cable etc etc) 


Im going to need a UART for that rpi-update I assume?

Comment: I have now gotten it to the point where the Pi ACT is (the green one) occasionally flashes / flickers? does that mean hope?

Comment: another update, plugged the PI into my pc and the pc (eventually) saw it come up as bcm2711 boot

Comment: explain how one runs memtester or rpi-update (or anything) on a pi that doesn't boot?

Comment: Suggesting to use unstable software under development with `rpi-update` is not a good idea to fix a hardware problem.

Comment: @JaromandaX well he said it sometimes boots. if it never boots we can't help him...